# Using CFLint in VS Code - can't seem to enable it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, coldfusion

I have a java 8 installed, and .jar file is where it's supposed to be, yet in my vscode settings file the lines to enable cflint appear to be dimmed out?

[image]

The hover error is "Unknown Configuration Setting".  Any tips on getting CFLint enabled?

Comment: Try `"cflint.enabled": true,`

Comment: Did you install this plugin, in the first place? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KamasamaK.vscode-cflint